# How could I check outdated extensions installed via Composer?

Tags: magento2, composer, third-party-module

I have 30 extensions installed via Composer but when I need to check all the outdated extensions running the command below a huge list of non-extensions shows up, containing all the dependencies and etc.

```
composer outdated
```

---

```
amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module    4.2.1      5.6.0      Official Magento2 Plugin to integrate with Amazon Pay and Login with Amazon
Package amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use amzn/amazon-pay-magento-2-module instead.
braintree/braintree_php                       5.2.0      6.4.1      Braintree PHP Client Library
colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis           1.11.0     1.14.2     Zend_Cache backend using Redis with full support for tags.
colinmollenhour/credis                        1.11.1     v1.12.1    Credis is a lightweight interface to the Redis key-value store which wraps ...
composer/composer                             1.10.22    2.1.5      Composer helps you declare, manage and install dependencies of PHP projects...
composer/semver                               1.7.2      3.2.5      Semver library that offers utilities, version constraint parsing and valida...
composer/xdebug-handler                       1.4.6      2.0.2      Restarts a process without Xdebug.
container-interop/container-interop           1.2.0      1.2.0      Promoting the interoperability of container objects (DIC, SL, etc.)
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
csharpru/vault-php-guzzle6-transport          2.0.4      2.0.4      Guzzle6 transport for Vault PHP client
Package csharpru/vault-php-guzzle6-transport is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
donatj/phpuseragentparser                     v0.20.0    v1.4.0     Lightning fast, minimalist PHP UserAgent string parser.
dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension        4.12.0     4.13.0     dotmailer integration for magento 2
elasticsearch/elasticsearch                   v7.11.0    v7.14.0    PHP Client for Elasticsearch
endroid/qr-code                               3.9.7      4.2.1      Endroid QR Code
friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer                     v2.18.7    v3.0.2     A tool to automatically fix PHP code style
guzzlehttp/guzzle                             6.5.5      7.3.0      Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library
guzzlehttp/psr7                               1.8.2      2.0.0      PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods
hoa/consistency                               1.17.05.02 2.17.08.29 The Hoa\Consistency library.
hoa/event                                     1.17.01.13 2.17.08.30 The Hoa\Event library.
hoa/exception                                 1.17.01.16 2.17.08.30 The Hoa\Exception library.
laminas/laminas-code                          3.5.1      4.4.2      Extensions to the PHP Reflection API, static code scanning, and code genera...
laminas/laminas-escaper                       2.7.0      2.8.0      Securely and safely escape HTML, HTML attributes, JavaScript, CSS, and URLs
league/iso3166                                2.1.5      3.0.0      ISO 3166-1 PHP Library
magento/composer                              1.6.0      1.7.0      Magento composer library helps to instantiate Composer application and run ...
magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.5.1      3.6.0      Magento2 Functional Testing Framework
monolog/monolog                               1.26.1     2.3.2      Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
nikic/php-parser                              v4.4.0     v4.12.0    A PHP parser written in PHP
pdepend/pdepend                               2.7.1      2.10.0     Official version of pdepend to be handled with Composer
phar-io/manifest                              1.0.3      2.0.3      Component for reading phar.io manifest information from a PHP Archive (PHAR)
phar-io/version                               2.0.1      3.1.0      Library for handling version information and constraints
php-amqplib/php-amqplib                       v2.10.1    v3.0.0     Formerly videlalvaro/php-amqplib.  This library is a pure PHP implementatio...
php-cs-fixer/diff                             v1.3.1     v2.0.2     sebastian/diff v2 backport support for PHP5.6
php-webdriver/webdriver                       1.8.2      1.11.1     A PHP client for Selenium WebDriver. Previously facebook/webdriver.
phpgt/dom                                     v2.1.6     v2.2.1     The modern DOM API for PHP 7 projects.
phpmd/phpmd                                   2.9.1      2.10.2     PHPMD is a spin-off project of PHP Depend and aims to be a PHP equivalent o...
phpseclib/mcrypt_compat                       1.0.8      2.0.0      PHP 7.1 polyfill for the mcrypt extension from PHP <= 7.0
phpseclib/phpseclib                           2.0.32     3.0.9      PHP Secure Communications Library - Pure-PHP implementations of RSA, AES, S...
phpunit/php-code-coverage                     8.0.2      9.2.6      Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality f...
phpunit/php-token-stream                      4.0.4      4.0.4      Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
phpunit/phpunit                               9.2.6      9.5.8      The PHP Unit Testing framework.
psr/container                                 1.1.1      2.0.1      Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
ramsey/uuid                                   4.1.1      4.2.1      A PHP library for generating and working with universally unique identifier...
sebastian/global-state                        4.0.0      5.0.3      Snapshotting of global state
squizlabs/php_codesniffer                     3.5.8      3.6.0      PHP_CodeSniffer tokenizes PHP, JavaScript and CSS files and detects violati...
symfony/console                               v4.4.29    v5.3.6     Eases the creation of beautiful and testable command line interfaces
symfony/error-handler                         v4.4.27    v5.3.4     Provides tools to manage errors and ease debugging PHP code
symfony/event-dispatcher                      v4.4.27    v5.3.4     Provides tools that allow your application components to communicate with e...
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts            v1.1.9     v2.4.0     Generic abstractions related to dispatching event
symfony/http-kernel                           v4.4.29    v5.3.6     Provides a structured process for converting a Request into a Response
symfony/process                               v4.4.27    v5.3.4     Executes commands in sub-processes
vlucas/phpdotenv                              v2.6.7     v5.3.0     Loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVE...
webonyx/graphql-php                           v0.13.9    v14.9.0    A PHP port of GraphQL reference implementation
```

How could I have a list of my outdated Composer extensions only?

Answer (score 3):

You're saying all the outdated Composer packages because the **--direct** parameter is missing, using it, you might see just the direct packages (your extensions in the composer.json) instead of all dependencies.

```
composer outdated --direct
```

---

```
allfriendsofphp/php-cs-fixer                  v2.18.7 v3.0.2 A tool to automatically fix PHP code style
magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.5.1   3.6.0  Magento2 Functional Testing Framework
pdepend/pdepend                               2.7.1   2.10.0 Official version of pdepend to be handled with Composer
phpmd/phpmd                                   2.9.1   2.10.2 PHPMD is a spin-off project of PHP Depend and aims to be a PHP equivalent of the w...
phpunit/phpunit                               9.2.6   9.5.8  The PHP Unit Testing framework.
squizlabs/php_codesniffer                     3.5.8   3.6.0  PHP_CodeSniffer tokenizes PHP, JavaScript and CSS files and detects violations of ...
```